# When to call findViewById in an Activity

Tags: android

I am encountering the following issue.
I have the following lines of code :

```
Spinner domainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.domain);
domainSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

These get executed after the user clicks on menu item in the UI. So I am pretty sure the UI is drawn on the screen. The spinner should be on the screen, and already filled with data.
The menu item is to change the language of the screen. The spinner should than fill up with items in the newly selected language.

In GooglePlay I sometimes get an error report where the stackTrace gives a NullPointerException in the 2nd line. So it must be that domainSpinner is null.

I have never experienced this issue myself. Also we use a beta version of the app for our own use, and none of my collegues has ever had this issue.

I have no idea why the findViewById should sometimes return null. I have tried going back and forward, rotating, .... But I never have this problem.

Note that the item R.id.domain can have a visibility of GONE setted programmatically. But I also played with this but could not reproduce the problem.

Code of the menu item action :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.action_nl)
   {
      changeLanguage("nl", true);
      return true;
   }
   else if (id == R.id.action_fr)
   {
      changeLanguage("fr", true);
      return true;
   }
   else if (id == R.id.action_en)
   {
      changeLanguage("en", true);
      return true;
   }
   else if (id == R.id.action_de)
   {
      changeLanguage("de", true);
      return true;
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

Comment: Please share your code snippet of setting onClickListener on the button.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the code segment could be called after an "onPause" call? Perhaps through some asynchronous mechanism.

Comment: might be some sort of race condition e.g. in some devices, the spinner view isn't added to view tree yet when it's getting called.

Comment: Also, you said that the visibility could be set to "GONE" later.  My guess is, the user is leaving the app and the NPE is from the "GONE" part.

Comment: That could indeed be the case DeeV....
Gonna test it by starting the app and then closing it for a while and re-open it and see what happens...

Comment: If you have the spinner in the XML layout that you are using in the Activity/fragment and aren't loading it programmatically on-demand and you are sure the id is correct, then findViewById should never return null, and it is safe to call it immediately after the setContentView(...) call in your activity, or if you are in a fragment you are safe to call it immediately after you inflate you view. But if you are getting null when a user clicks the a button, and you try to look up the view, it could be an incorrect id issue.

Comment: The ID surely is correct, as this problem only occurs sometimes. Most of the time it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always initialise your views on the OnCreate method in an activity to make sure the view exists when you want to reference it. 
Like below:

```
private Spinner domainSpinner;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        domainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.domain);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps!

UPDATE: If you need to use the variable outside of the on create method, then declare a global variable and still initialise it on create, then use it where needed.

Comment: Ihave read this before but I actually avoid this because member variables, even static variables become null when the device goes to sleep and android clears up memory. I have seen this myself, and if you google for 'android member variables becoming null' or 'android static becoming null' you will find lots of other people having this issue.

Comment: I have implemented this anwser and will look into it for a week to see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Make sure the domainSpinner is initialized on the Main Thread. Also add a condition for setting visibility only when domainSpinner is not equal to null.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Spinner domainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.domain);
        if(domainSpinner!=null) {
           domainSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```